# Youtube IFrame API - Not Registering Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

For the past few hours, I've been struggling with getting several iFrames on a page, to stop an audio player when the video is started. Fortunately, and with the help of other answers, I was able to use the following code to resolve most of it...:

```
<script>

function getFrameID(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem) {
        if(/^iframe$/i.test(elem.tagName)) return id; //Frame, OK
        // else: Look for frame
        var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        if (!elems.length) return null; //No iframe found, FAILURE
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
           if (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(elems[i].src)) break;
        }
        elem = elems[i]; //The only, or the best iFrame
        if (elem.id) return elem.id; //Existing ID, return it
        // else: Create a new ID
        do { //Keep postfixing `-frame` until the ID is unique
            id += "-frame";
        } while (document.getElementById(id));
        elem.id = id;
        return id;
    }
    // If no element, return null.
    return null;
}

// Define YT_ready function.
var YT_ready = (function() {
    var onReady_funcs = [], api_isReady = false;
    /* @param func function     Function to execute on ready
     * @param func Boolean      If true, all qeued functions are executed
     * @param b_before Boolean  If true, the func will added to the first
                                 position in the queue*/
    return function(func, b_before) {
        if (func === true) {
            api_isReady = true;
            while (onReady_funcs.length) {
                // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func
                onReady_funcs.shift()();
            }
        } else if (typeof func == "function") {
            if (api_isReady) func();
            else onReady_funcs[b_before?"unshift":"push"](func);
        }
    }
})();
// This function will be called when the API is fully loaded
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {YT_ready(true)}

// Load YouTube Frame API
(function() { // Closure, to not leak to the scope
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = (location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https' : 'http') + "://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);
})();

var players = {}; //Define a player storage object, to expose methods,
                  //  without having to create a new class instance again.
YT_ready(function() {
    jQuery("iframe[id]").each(function() {
        var identifier = this.id;
        var frameID = getFrameID(identifier);
        if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
            players[frameID] = new YT.Player(frameID, {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("playing!");
        jQuery('.sp-show-player.playing a.sp-play-button').click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Essentially, when I place an iFrame directly into the source, it works. However, when an iFrame is brought in via a jQuery slider extension (in this case, Revolution Slider), the state change is not being recognized. I can literally copy the iFrame code from the source generated, paste it in, and it works. I'm not sure if perhaps I need to add a delay somewhere, but I'd really appreciate the help.

As a reference point, I have an example of an iFrame I'm using, and this code works when placed into the actual page (via HTML). However, when being delivered via the slider (with the same iFrame code, digit by digit), it does not work.

```
<iframe style="display: block; width: 1840px; height: 900px; transform-style: preserve-3d; z-index: 0; visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DSXz9xst5k?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1;" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe27350" class="HasListener"></iframe>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to delay the Youtube API, to let the slider load? I don't know how much documentation I'll be able to find on their slider, unfortunately.

Comment: In fact @SamuelLiew, you were right. I just referenced the API docs for the slider, and have used that to fix my problem. I think I was assuming it'd be incomplete. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :-)